# mysqli create multplie table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I want to create multiple table using `mysqli::multi_query` but with some reason it seems my coding didn't execute properly.

I think the problem is at execute multiple. Currently my database doesn't have any required tables, so it should execute `CreateTable` function.

`CODE`:

```
<?php

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected database successfully";


/* create table in database */

function CreateTable($conn) {

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE Address(
                    id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    Unit VARCHAR (20),
                    Lot VARCHAR(20),
                    FloorNumber VARCHAR(5),
                    BuildingName VARCHAR(50),
                    HighorLand VARCHAR (10),
                    StreetName VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                    City VARCHAR(15)NOT NULL,
                    Postcode VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
                    State VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
                    reg_date TIMESTAMP);";

    $sql .= "CREATE TABLE HomeUser(
                    Hid INT(100) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    HName VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
                    HNRIC VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
                    HContatcnum VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
                    HEmail VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                    HPromocode VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
                    HICFront VARCHAR (80),
                    HICBack VARCHAR (80),
                    HUtilitybill VARCHAR (80));";

    $sql .= "CREATE TABLE BusinessUser(
                    Bid INT(100) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    BName VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
                    BEmail VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                    BComregnum VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
                    BContactnum VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
                    BNoemployee INT (5),
                    BPromocode VARCHAR (10),
                    BForm9 VARCHAR (80),
                    BForm24 VARCHAR (80),
                    BForm49 VARCHAR (80),
                    BDirectoric VARCHAR (80));";

    /* execute multi query */
    if (($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Table created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}

/* Check table exist or not,if exist insert data,if not create table and insert data */

$CheckTable = tep_db_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'Address'");
if (tep_db_num_rows($CheckTable) > 0) {
    echo 'Table exists';
} else {
    CreateTable($conn);
}


/* close connection */
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Don't see any connection details on your code. Paste that in as well please.

Comment: @Syfer i already update connection information

Comment: Hope you have necessary mysql user privileges for creating tables.

Comment: missing parenthesis near muti query if   *if (($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {*    it should be if (($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE)) {

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli::multi_query` *is not what it seems.*

Unlike other PHP functions, it is not that permissive towards cargo cult programming. In order to use it, you need to have some experience in PHP and the habit of reading PHP manual thoroughly.

So it's better to avoid this function for a while and use simple reqular mysqli_query(), running your queries on the spot instead of collecting them in a single monster statement

```
function CreateTable($conn) {

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE Address(
                    id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    Unit VARCHAR (20),
                    Lot VARCHAR(20),
                    FloorNumber VARCHAR(5),
                    BuildingName VARCHAR(50),
                    HighorLand VARCHAR (10),
                    StreetName VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                    City VARCHAR(15)NOT NULL,
                    Postcode VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
                    State VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
                    reg_date TIMESTAMP);";

    $conn->query($sql);
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE HomeUser(
                    Hid INT(100) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    HName VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
                    HNRIC VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
                    HContatcnum VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
                    HEmail VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                    HPromocode VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
                    HICFront VARCHAR (80),
                    HICBack VARCHAR (80),
                    HUtilitybill VARCHAR (80));";
    $conn->query($sql);
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE BusinessUser(
                    Bid INT(100) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    BName VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
                    BEmail VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                    BComregnum VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
                    BContactnum VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
                    BNoemployee INT (5),
                    BPromocode VARCHAR (10),
                    BForm9 VARCHAR (80),
                    BForm24 VARCHAR (80),
                    BForm49 VARCHAR (80),
                    BDirectoric VARCHAR (80));";
    $conn->query($sql);
}
```

It will work like a charm